# problem selecting, typing and copying with keyboard in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sorry for the english, but I'm having a problem when selecting, typing and copying in visual studio code. It looks like some key is being activated, but only in the app. The problem is a month old, but I solved it by pressing "Insert Prt Sc", but today nothing works.
Below is an image of how the cursor is selected. This way it doesn't allow you to select, type or copy correctly.
enter image description here

1: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDtZf.jpg

Comment: Please upload your screenshot.

Comment: @FredericChang can't load image with low reputation